# CPT, meta-data, url parameter

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, search

does someone could point me a lecture that could explain me how to create some "filter" passed by pretty link ?

Let me explain my self, I have a custom post type called **"spectacle"** and I have a meta_key  who contain an array of dates for this spectacle. I know how to extract my date, and filter them if I give explicitly some filter to my display, my problem is not coming from there, what I'm trying to achieve, is to access

> http://myurl.com/spectacles (show upcoming spectacles - **already done**)
>   http://myurl.com/spectacles/2014 (show all 2014 spectacle)
>   http://myurl.com/spectacles/2014/01 (show all spectacle from january 2014)
>   http://myurl.com/spectacles/2014/01/01 (show all spectacle from january 1st 2014)
>   http://myurl.com/spectacle/name-of-the-spectacle (show this spectacle - **already done**)

All i need to is a way to enable theses permalink and to extract theses parameters than i'll be able to do what I want, I already have my filtering functions.

This is what i've done so far :

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function build_cpt() {
$labels  = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Programmation', 'Post Type General Name', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Spectacles', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'menu_name'          => __( 'Programmation', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'Tous les spectacles', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'Afficher ce spectacle', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Ajouter un spectacle', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'add_new'            => __( 'Ajouter un spectacle', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Modifier un spectacle', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'update_item'        => __( 'Mettre à jour ce spectacle', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Rechercher un spectacle', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'Aucun spectacle trouvé', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Aucun spectacle dans la corbeille', 'mlog_lang' ),
);

add_rewrite_tag( '%event-year%', '(\d{4})' );
//add_rewrite_tag( '%event-month%', '(\d{2})' );
//add_rewrite_tag( '%event-day%', '(\d{2}|\d{1})' );

$rewrite = array(
    //'slug'       => 'spectacles/%event-year%/%event-month%/%event-day%/',
    'slug'       => 'spectacles/%event-year%/',
    'with_front' => true,
    'pages'      => true,
    'feeds'      => true,
);
$args    = array(
    'label'               => __( 'programmation', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Liste des spectacles', 'mlog_lang' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions' ),
    'taxonomies'          => array(),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => false,
    'menu_position'       => 4,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-groups',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'programmation', $args );
```

Now I can access :

> http://myurl.com/spectacles/2014

but it shows the home page instead of archive-programmation.php

And I can't access :

> http://myurl.com/spectacles/name-of-the-spectacle

Comment: you need to add rewrite rules, search this site for `add_rewrite_rule` for some examples.

Comment: I tried that solution, but there's two problem to address, first when I had let say `add_rewrite_tag( '%event-year%', '(\d{4})' );` I can access http://myurl.com/spectacle/2014 but I can't access http://myurl.com/spectacle AND the second problem is that http://myurl.com/spectacle/2014 show me the front-page instead of the archive-spectacle.php !

Comment: I said *rule* not *tag*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good answer was from @Milo, but he haven't posted any code, so I post here my result, for people coming here for the right answer.

```
/* Add query var to authorized query var... */
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_spectacles_query_vars' );
function add_spectacles_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'spectacles-year';
    $query_vars[] = 'spectacles-month';
    $query_vars[] = 'spectacles-day';
    return $query_vars;
}

/* Add rewrite rule */
add_action( 'init', 'add_spectacles_rewrite_rule' );
function add_spectacles_rewrite_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'spectacles\/(on){1}\/{1}(\d{4})+\/?(\d{2})?\/?(\d{2}|d{1})?',
        'index.php?post_type=programmation&spectacles-year=$matches[2]&spectacles-month=$matches[3]&spectacles-day=$matches[4]',
        'top'
    );
    //flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Than in my template I can go with

```
$spectacle_year = get_query_var('spectacles-year');
$spectacle_month = get_query_var('spectacles-month');
$spectacle_day = get_query_var('spectacles-day');
```

P.S. I'm filtering my spectacles directly in the archive page, but it could be done via :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'spectacles_archvies_pre_get_posts', 11 );
function spectacles_archvies_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if( !empty($query->query_vars['spectacles-year']) ) {
        /* Do your stuff here... */
    }
}
```